# Send numeric value from PowerShell to VBA

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

I'd like to get some numeric values that I receive via a PowerShell script to an Excel sheet. I can already get the value back but it arrives to the spreadsheet as a string and somehow Excel won't allow me to convert it to a number.
I hope I'm just missing a step and it's not impossible.

This is the VBA part

```vb
strCommand = (PsCommand)
Set wshshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShellexec = wshshell.Exec(strCommand)
stroutput = WshShellexec.StdOut.ReadAll
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = stroutput
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0"
```

My guess is that this here is the problem:

```vb
Set WshShellexec = wshshell.Exec(strCommand)
```

Comment: `Exec` runs commands asynchronously, but since `ReadAll` is blocking that shouldn't be an issue here (unless the external command generates excessive output, so the buffer is filled up). What is `PsCommand`?

Comment: `.Value = Val(stroutput)` ?

Comment: PsCommand = "Powershell -File c:\script\FolderSizeCheck\FolderSizev2.ps1 " & TargetFolder

Comment: How can I get an integer back instead of a string? Targetfolder may contain a space. But those were also identified by the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReadAll` always returns a string. To convert a number string to an integer use [`CInt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fctcwhw9.aspx) or [`CLng`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck4c5842.aspx):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = CLng(stroutput)
```

Note that the string must consist of just a number (leading and trailing whitespace is okay). Other characters in the string will lead to an error. In such a case you'd need to parse the value out of the string first before converting it to an integer.

Comment: I tried this and seems to be the code part I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the help!!! :)